# 3D arrays with python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to make battleships, and I am assuming I am missing something really obvious but I can not see it... the program is VERY early and at the moment just suppose to create a table you can edit the contents of... but anyways, here it is so far... please post correction because entire x axis of chosen column gets the input...

```
a_user = [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
b_user = a_user
c_user = a_user
d_user = a_user
e_user = a_user
f_user = a_user
g_user = a_user
h_user = a_user
y_arr = [a_user,b_user,c_user,d_user,e_user,f_user,g_user,h_user]
def draw_Table():
    print('    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8')
    print('  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+')
    print('1 |',a_user[0],'|',a_user[1],'|',a_user[2],'|',a_user[3],'|',a_user[4],'|',a_user[5],'|',a_user[6],'|',a_user[7],'|')
    print('  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+')
    print('2 |',b_user[0],'|',b_user[1],'|',b_user[2],'|',b_user[3],'|',b_user[4],'|',b_user[5],'|',b_user[6],'|',b_user[7],'|')
    print('  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+')
    print('3 |',c_user[0],'|',c_user[1],'|',c_user[2],'|',c_user[3],'|',c_user[4],'|',c_user[5],'|',c_user[6],'|',c_user[7],'|')
    print('  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+')
    print('4 |',d_user[0],'|',d_user[1],'|',d_user[2],'|',d_user[3],'|',d_user[4],'|',d_user[5],'|',d_user[6],'|',d_user[7],'|')
    print('  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+')
    print('5 |',e_user[0],'|',e_user[1],'|',e_user[2],'|',e_user[3],'|',e_user[4],'|',e_user[5],'|',e_user[6],'|',e_user[7],'|')
    print('  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+')
    print('6 |',f_user[0],'|',f_user[1],'|',f_user[2],'|',f_user[3],'|',f_user[4],'|',f_user[5],'|',f_user[6],'|',f_user[7],'|')
    print('  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+')
    print('7 |',g_user[0],'|',g_user[1],'|',g_user[2],'|',g_user[3],'|',g_user[4],'|',g_user[5],'|',g_user[6],'|',g_user[7],'|')
    print('  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+')
    print('8 |',h_user[0],'|',h_user[1],'|',h_user[2],'|',h_user[3],'|',h_user[4],'|',h_user[5],'|',h_user[6],'|',h_user[7],'|')
    print('  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+')
while 1:
    draw_Table()
    x_axis = int(input('Enter a x coord\n')) - 1
    y_axis = int(input('Enter a y coord\n')) - 1
    y_arr[y_axis][x_axis] = 'o'
```

Comment: Lists are passed and assigned by reference in python.

Comment: @mniip Just like everything else. :-) Or a different look at this: Every variable refers to some object, and objects are never copied on assignment

Answer (score 3):

You are filling the list `y_arr` with *multiple references to the same list*, `a_user`.

The assignment:

```
b_user = a_user
```

**does not** create a copy of `a_user` and call it `b_user`, it makes the name `b_user` a reference to the exact same object that the name `a_user` references.

You can demonstrate this using [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id), where the same value means the same object:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> id(a)
53575512
>>> id(b)
53575512 # exactly the same object
```

Instead, you need to create separate lists. The minimal fix is to make each variable a *copy* of the list, for example:

```
b_user = a_user[:]
```

Which for the trivial example gives:

```
>>> b = a[:]
>>> id(a)
53575512 # still the same
>>> id(b)
53770480 # separate object
```

However, this is usually done with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which is considerably neater:

```
y_arr = [[" " for _ in range(8)] for _ in range(8)]
```

Also, you can make your printing much neater with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), e.g.

```
for index, row in enumerate(y_arr, 1):
    print("{0} |{1}|".format(index, "|".join(row)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this

```
b_user = a_user
c_user = a_user
d_user = a_user
e_user = a_user
f_user = a_user
g_user = a_user
h_user = a_user
```

It will not copy the contents of those lists, it will copy a reference to the lists themselves. So all the *_users are references to the same list. If you change an item in `a_user`, it changes for every user.

What you could do instead is

```
a_user = [' '] * 8
```

Perhaps you could also make a list `users`, as such

```
users = []
user[0] = [' '] * 8
user[1] = [' '] * 8
...
```

Which could then be shortened to:

```
users = [[' '] * 8 for k in range(8)]
```

If you prefer letters for your users, you could turn it into a dictionary.

Comment: Assignments don't copy the lists. Please re-word.